# Windows login using OpenLDAP

Tags: windows, authentication, openldap

I have an OpenLDAP server that I use to authenticate users in Unix systems and some network equipment. Now I want to provide access to Windows servers.
Im looking for a method that a user in the LDAP server can logon using his user and password to any Windows server. 
I have read that Windows needs an Active Directory to do so, or a Samba server but those systems don't connect to an OpenLDAP server.
I have also tried [pGina](http://pgina.org/) and works fine for my requeriments, but I want to know if it exists any other method of authentication to allow the logon of OpenLDAP users in Windows systems.
The solution doesn't need to be OpenSource.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with Samba 3. Samba 3 can use openldap as a backend. But samba 3 can not mimick an AD. Thus you will logon to a Windows NT domain.

Samba 4 comes with its own LDAP backend but can mimick an AD. Then you would have to sync your users between openldap and Samba 4.

You may also want to take a look at the univention corporate server.